# Want to customize EditText attribute with a hint

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

I'm new to android mobile development and java. And wonder if anybody can help me with my issue.

Now, I'm making XML file of my android app and want it to have something like displayed below.

[image]

Can it be made in XML file without deep knowledge of java? I just want to have fixed text in my `EditText` attribute. Using `LinearLayout` to my first app. I appreciate any kind of help.

Using API 28 for testing.

Comment: And what is stopping you from making that? XML and Java are two different things checkout some tutorials you will get to know And Welcome to stackoverflow.com

Comment: thanks. i'm a newbie to mobile android development and I'll have a bunch of other questions related to making android apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a default layout `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText`.
Here's documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout
https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/

Answer (score 0):

This is called TextInputLayout.Read [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout). Demo example [here](https://www.journaldev.com/14748/android-textinputlayout-example)

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintEnabled="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Username" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`TextInputLayout`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md) component:

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Username"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/text_input_layout_stroke_color"
        app:counterMaxLength="15"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]
[image]